# "A reality" vs "reality"

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

*help [something] become **a** reality*

or

*help [something] become reality*

What would be the reason to use / not to use the article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reality](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reality) is a mass noun covering the state or quality of having existence or substance. Despite this, I think that the better sentence is:

> help [something] become **a** reality

(see below and comments for exploration)

You could replace the second with:

> help [something] become real

[Mass nouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun) have the syntactic property that any quantity of [the noun] is treated as an undifferentiated unit, rather than as something with discrete subsets. 'This is reality.'

Confusingly however, as is explained more fully in the dialogue between @EdwinAshworth and myself in the comments, mass nouns can also be used as count nouns (i.e. those that can be counted in some capacity) in some circumstances.

In the case of 'reality' it can be counted as unitary 'become a reality', 'the reality is...' (in which case it requires an article, see below for a more clear-cut example) or plural, as long as the plural doesn't have a specified number, 'the realities of life'. This plural 'realities' I think is an example of something that is grammatically wrong becoming common speech, because 'the reality of life' is a statement that covers exactly the same meaning without betraying the definition of a mass noun.

To demonstrate how a unitary quantity of something requires an article, 'a dog', 'the car' etc, compare for analogy:

> help [something] become a car

vs

> help [something] become car

Comment: This is confused.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth give me a bit more to work with and I'll edit it.

Comment: (1) 'Reality is a mass noun' [I'll come back to this]. (2)'In English, mass nouns are characterized by the fact that they cannot be directly modified by a numeral without specifying a unit of measurement, and that they cannot combine with an indefinite article (a or an).' [Wikipedia] I'm not sure if you say this or not. (3) 'The correct sentence is: "help [something] become a reality" '. // [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/reality) labels OP's first variant as a count usage of 'reality'. // I might just say idioms can break the rules.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ok, so to check I'm following: Reality according to the dictionary is a mass noun, which I have evidently misunderstood the definition of, but can also be used as a count noun, despite the only count values that I can find example of being singular (such as in OP) or undefined plural e.g. realities of life. Given that it is a mass noun, I find it interesting that the idiomatic uses I know it in are count, and that it has a defined plural. Also somewhat amusing how an intuitive command of English can shortfall when one attempts to backfill grammatical reasoning!

Comment: The whole count / mass / other debate is far from resolved. In 'we weighed anchor', is 'anchor' count or mass? I'd say it doesn't fit neatly into either camp. (There's no problem with 'the carrier has six anchors', of course.) Sometimes, it doesn't make sense to force an analysis which works fine elsewhere. 'Become [a] reality' is listed as a collocation at least by some authorities (Collins Spanish - English). It's not easy to explain why both 'a' and the zero article may both be used.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have edited the answer to reflect our dialogue, does it make better sense now?

Comment: You still say " 'help [something] become a reality' is the correct sentence" although **both** variants are used. And this after arguing in the first sentence for a mass-noun usage, which would strongly suggest the zero article would be the correct option. But can we even be sure the count / mass analysis works? Behrens [(see here)](http://www.uta.edu/faculty/stvan/stvan98_ch2.pdf) carried out an extensive review of work on count nouns. She concluded that various possible interpretations of the same noun form make “the categoriality of the MASS/COUNT distinction doubtful” (Behrens 1995:12)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think that the notion of mass/count distinction being essentially contextual resonates. Given just this particular example, it can clearly be more complex. I still dislike the second sentence in this specific context, perhaps it may be as simple as the appeal of the symmetry between 'help a/an [thing] become a reality' vs 'help [intangible] become reality, and the [something] predisposed me to the former, where a more concrete example might not necessarily have.

Answer (score 3):

Using idiomatic expressions. [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=become+reality%2Cbecome+a+reality&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbecome%20reality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbecome%20a%20reality%3B%2Cc0) back up my judgement that 'become a reality' is more commonly used than 'become reality' (which is not, however, incorrect).

In your question title, you don't put the full idiom you later ask about, and I'd say that, in general, *reality* is used as a mass noun more often (thus without the 'a').

Comment: In this context it should be *becomes* not *become*. Or maybe not. I don't know what he means by the *something* part.

Comment: No it shouldn't, because I've chosen to look up the versions I've chosen. It's my choice of context. And I chose it as being appropriate to OP's query.

Comment: What would be an example for *becomes* in this context?

Comment: Are you missing OP's catenation here? 'Hard work will help your dreams become a reality.' // 'If their plan becomes a reality, we'll all be in trouble.'